# Conserver Space by Putting PDU and Cisco 3500XL Switch on Same U?

Tags: rackspace

Is it possible to have two appliances on 1U in a Rack. Both the PDU and the Cisco switch are very short, I was wondering if it is doable to have one on the front and one on the back. I just purchased a quarter rack and having the extra space could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for certain, but I imagine that at least the 3500XL is designed to move air from the front to the back. If the PDU blocks or hinders the airflow, this might be bad for the switch. But if the PDU is small enough, it may not matter.

In summary, its certainly *possible*, but ultimately deciding whether it is a good idea or not will depend on your airflow/cooling situation.